# ¿Cómo insertar un nodo entre dos nodos en una lista enlazada en Java?

Tags: java, lista, nodos

Tengo un problema: no sé como insertar un elemento entre dos nodos en una lista enlazada.

Hasta ahora tengo este código. ¿Qué puedo hacer? Sé que primero debo buscar el nodo a partir del cual se agregará. Tengo el método, está en la lista que se encarga de buscar los nodos, pero a partir de aquí no sé con qué más deba proceder:

```
public class Lista<T> {

    protected Nodo primero, ultimo;
    T p;

    public Lista() {
        primero = null;
        ultimo = null;
    }

    public boolean EstaVacia() {
        if (primero == null) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void visualizar() {
        Nodo<Integer> n = primero;
        System.out.println();
        while (n != null) {
            System.out.print("[" + n.dato + "]-->");
            n = n.enlace;
        }
    }

    //Eliminar un nodo especifico
    public void eliminar(T p) {
        if (!EstaVacia()) {
            if (primero == ultimo && p == primero.dato) {
                primero = ultimo = null;
            } else if (p == primero.dato) {
                primero = primero.enlace;
            } else {
                Nodo anterior, temporal;
                anterior = primero;
                temporal = primero.enlace;
                while (temporal != null && temporal.dato != p) {
                    anterior = anterior.enlace;
                    temporal = temporal.enlace;
                }
                if (temporal != null) {
                    anterior.enlace = temporal.enlace;
                    if (temporal == ultimo) {
                        ultimo = anterior;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // buscar si un elemnento se encunetra en la lista
    public boolean EstaEnLaLista(T p) {
        Nodo temporal = primero;
        while (temporal != null && temporal.dato != p) {
            temporal = temporal.enlace;
        }
        return temporal != null;
    }
```

Espero me puedan ayudar. Esta es mi clase Nodo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, puedes proporcionar la estructura de la clase Nodo?

Comment: si claro la paso

Comment: En el metodo que queres hacer, recibis un Nodo<T> y el que queres agregar es entre el anterior y Nodo<T>o el posterior y Nodo<T>?

Comment: si mira ejemplo el usuario ingresa al inicio de la lista los siguientes datos: [3]-->[2]-->[1] y tengo  una opción donde le pregunto si desea agregar algún otro numero entre los números que se encuentran en la lista si escoge esa opción quiero que ingrese el numero que desea añadir y en donde lo quiere añadir si lo quiere que sea entre 3 y 2 o después el uno esa es la idea

Comment: si por ejemplo en esa lista con esos valores te pide entre 3 y 1 donde deberia ponerlo? yo pensaria la pregunta como antes o despues de un numero; otra cosa si hay valores repetidos?

Comment: Mas bien lo que debo de preguntar es en que posición lo debo de agregar el nuevo numero si tenemos: [3]-->[2]-->[1]  y el usuario lo quiere en la posicion 1 que lo agregue después del 3 lo cual quedaría así: [3]-->[12]-->[2]-->[1]-->

Comment: bien el metodo seria entonces seria addAfter(Nodo, elemento); no seria Nodo sino Position<T>, habria que modificar un poco la clase Nodo<T>, hay que agregarle un metodo mas y hay que implementar la interface Position<T>.  Si queres te lo explico.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente

```
private void insertar(Nodo nodo,int posicion)
{
    Nodo temporal = primero;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < posicion && temporal.enlace != null){
        i++;
        temporal = temporal.enlace;
    }
    nodo.enlace = temporal.enlace;
    temporal.enlace = nodo;
}
```

Comment: Ok una pregunta mas al momento de probarlo le tengo que pedir al usuario el nodo a partir de cual se ingresara el otro y la posición?

Comment: Así es, la idea es que inyectes la información y posición, está la debes de pedir en otro lugar de tu programa, ya que tu clase debe hacer solo una cosa y es el manejo de una lista simple ligada, por lo que solamente debes tener cierto comportamiento (insertar, eliminar, recuperar, etc) Esto es lo más básico que puedes hacer, supongo que estás aprendiendo estructuras de datos, por lo que trata de entender lo más simple que puedas, ya si le quieres meter más lógica o mejor estructura eso vendrá con la práctica

Answer (score 1):

> El cliente de tu clase lista, no debe recibir ni enviar variables de tipo NodoT, porque el cliente no tiene que tener acceso a la estructura. Para cubrir eso la clase NodoT tiene que implementar la interfaz Position.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public interface Position<T>{
 public T element();
}
```

> La implementacion en el nodo seria así

```
public class Nodo<T> implements Position<T>{
   private Nodo<T> siguiete;
   private T elemento;
//Constructor
public T element(){
 return elemento;
}

//getters y setters.
}
```

> Si por ejemplo queres agregar un método a tu lista para que te devuelva el primer elemento, tendrías que devolverlo tipo Position

```
//este método arrojaría una excepción si la lista estuviera vacía. 
public Position<T> primero(){
  return head;
}
```

> Acá pasa algo interesante, head es de tipo Nodo sin embargo el metodo devuelve una Posicion y no un Nodo, esto es porque la clase Nodo implementa a la interface Position, tiene que ver con lo que se llama polimorfismo.

Ahora vamos al metodo addAfter(Posicion,Elemento);

```
//aca habria que ver el tema del manejo de excepciones, pero esa es otra historia.
public void addAfter(Position<T> pos, T elemento){
   //chequeo la posicion;
   Nodo<T> nodo=null;
   if(lista.tamaño==0)
      System.out.println("Lista vacia");
   else if(pos==null)
      System.out.println("Posicion nula");
   else{
     try{
       //aca le digo al compilador que la posicion que recibo es un nodo.
       nodo=(Nodo<T>)pos;
     }catch(ClassCastException e){
       System.out.println("Error de casteo"); 
       }

       //acá va el código
  }

}
}
```

> Donde pongo los System.out.prtinln(), van las excepciones, antes de seguir vamos a ver un gráfico de lo que queremos hacer.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Agregar un elemento después de la Posición P2

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Ahora si, donde decia Aca va el codigo ponemos.

```
Nodo<T> nuevo = new Nodo<T>(elemento);
nuevo.setSiguiente(nodo.getSiguiete());
nodo.setSiguiente(nuevo);
tamaño++;
```

> Cómo lo usa la clase cliente, por ejemplo el main

```
Lista<Integer> lista = new Lisa<Integer>();
lista.agregarPrimero(3);
lista.agregarPrimero(2);
lista.agregarPrimero(1);

Position<Integer> primero = lista.primero();
Position<Integer> segundo = lista.siguiete(primero);
lista.addAfter(segundo,14);
```

Comment: muchas gracias muy bien explicado solo una pregunta mas lista.tamaño==0 ¿como determino el tamaño de mi lista?

Comment: ¿tengo que hacer un método que me calcule el tamaño de la lista?

Comment: a tu lista, le agregas un atributo entero llamado tamaño ; en el constructor le pones tamaño=0 y cada vez que agregas un nuevo nodo haces tamao++ y cada vez que quitas uno  tamaño--, y despues te haces un metodo que sea un getTamaño, con tamaño==0 pregunto si la lista esta vacia.

Comment: Si respondi a tu pregunta, ponela como respondida.

Comment: Pregunta respondida

Comment: @Torniceli601 Si esta respuesta ha respondido correctamente a tu pregunta, por favor, márcala como aceptada.